# ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TrackCollection}" have no data. Please help me to fix it

Tags: c#, mvvm

Xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TrackCollection}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
..............
```

Json:

```
    public class Track
        {
            public string urn { get; set; }
            public string uri { get; set; }
            public string permalink { get; set; }
            public string permalink_url { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string track_type { get; set; }
            public string genre { get; set; }
            public string tag_list { get; set; }
................
         }
 public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Track> tracks { get; set; }
            public string tag { get; set; }
            public string next_href { get; set; }
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<TracksSoundCloud> TrackCollection = new ObservableCollection<TracksSoundCloud>();

    public async Task GetTrackAsyncTask(string link)
    {
        var result = await StaticMethod.GetJsonStringTask(link);
        if(result!=null)
        {
            var getItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TracksSoundCloud.RootObject>(result);
            //TrackCollection.Add(getItem.tracks);
        }
    }
```

if I use "TrackCollection.Add(getItem.tracks);" and then

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1503  Argument 1:
>   cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'EntertaimentGroup.Model.TracksSoundCloud'    EntertaimentGroup   C:\Users\HOANG-PC\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\EntertaimentGroup\EntertaimentGroup\ViewModel\TrackSoundCloudViewModel.cs   22

ViewModel:

```
public class StaticMethod
{

    public static async Task<string> GetJsonStringTask(string link)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(link+ "&client_id=9ac2b17027e4af068adbb4f10330e1b3");
        string result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exeption message says it all: `getItem.tracks` is a `List<Track>` while the elements of your `TrackCollection` are of type `TrackSoundCloud`.

You either need to change `TrackCollection` to `ObservableCollection<TrackSoundCloud>` or you need to convert your `Track`-objects `TrackSoundCloud`-objects.

Furthermore you are trying to add the whole collection instead of single items.

```
public ObservableCollection<Track> TrackCollection = new ObservableCollection<Track>();

public async Task GetTrackAsyncTask(string link)
{
    var result = await StaticMethod.GetJsonStringTask(link);
    if(result!=null)
    {
        var getItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TracksSoundCloud.RootObject>(result);
        foreach ( var item in getItem.tracks)
        {
            TrackCollection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public ObservableCollection<TracksSoundCloud> TrackCollection = new ObservableCollection<TracksSoundCloud>();

public async Task GetTrackAsyncTask(string link)
{
    var result = await StaticMethod.GetJsonStringTask(link);
    if(result!=null)
    {
        var getItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TracksSoundCloud.RootObject>(result);
        foreach ( var item in getItem.tracks)
        {
            TracksSoundCloud t = ConvertTrackToTracksSoundCloud(item);//<-- Needs to be implemented
            TrackCollection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```